# What's wrong with my boundary

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the triple integral $$\iiint_E x^8 e^y \,dV$$ where $E$ is bounded by the parabolic cylinder $z=4−y^2$ and the planes $z=0,x=2$, and $x=−2$.

I used boundary dxdzdy(BADCFE):
B: 2
A: -2
D: 4
C: 0
F: sqrt(4-z)
E: 0

the answer is 2500 something?
how can I get the right boundary

Comment: I think you should change the integration order and put $dx$ last.That's because it's the easiest to compute as the geometry doesn't change in that direction.

Comment: It is very hard to read what you have written as bounds but one of the mistakes I can clearly see is lower bound of $y$ as $0$. That is not correct. The parabola is along $z$ axis and the curve extends on both sides of $z$ axis $(-y, +y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically on your boundary -

it is a parabolic cylinder and the parabola ($y^2 = 4 - z$) is in $YZ$ plane. Values of $x$ is bound by the planes $x = -2, x = 2$.

So your bounds can be -

$-2 \leq x \leq 2$

$- \sqrt{4-z} \leq y \leq \sqrt{4-z}$

$0 \leq z \leq 4$ (bound below by the plane $z = 0$)

And if you are using above bounds, the order of integral should have $dy$ first and then $dz$. $dx$ can be pretty much in any spot - keep it first or last, does not matter.

If you go with order $dz$ then $dy$, the bounds of $y, z$ will be -

$0 \leq z \leq 4-y^2$

$-2 \leq y \leq 2$